# how to make variable name dynamic

Tags: python

I have a text file that has data like this:

```
0.90
0.43
6.03
-0.43
0.9
```

and I want my program to read the data and store each line in a new variable where the variable name increases automatically like this:

```
v1 = 0.9
v2 = 0.43
v3 = 6.03
v4 = -0.43
v5 = 0.9
```

I have tried this but it didn't work:

```
s = open("Lines_only.txt", "r")
j = 1
for i in s:
    line = i.strip()
    v[j] = float(line)
    print(v[j])
    j +=1
s.close()
```

Comment: This is what lists & dictionaries are for.

Comment: Great question! Check out this helpful answer on a similar question [How to define variables dynamically in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68507842/how-to-define-variables-dynamically-in-python)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The proper way to do it would be to use a dictionary rather than declaring variables :

```py
s = open("Lines_only.txt", "r")
j = 1
v_dict = {}
for i in s:
    line = i.strip()
    v_dict[f"v{j}"] = float(line)
    print(v_dict[f"v{j}"] )
    j +=1
s.close() 

#Then here access to the variables using v_dict["v1"], v_dict["v2"], ...
```

However, if what you want is really to declare a variable this is possible too (but you should still use the first option if possible)

```py
s = open("Lines_only.txt", "r")
j = 1
v_dict = {}
for i in s:
    line = i.strip()
    globals()[f"v{j}"] = float(line)
    print(globals()[f"v{j}"])
    j +=1
s.close() 

#Then here access to the variables using v1,v2, ... 
sum_result = v1+v2
```

Comment: I don't think you get much value from a dict over a list when the names are just consecutively numbered.

Comment: That's true, the idea was just to keep the `vx` notation, but a list do the job as well

Comment: @Xiidref the 2nd one worked ! Thanks a lot but why everyone warns me from using this style?!

Comment: @youssef Mostly because it can be really tricky to understand the code later, for example you can have `v3` used somewhere in the code but nowhere with `v3=...` this can make things hard to understand and debug. Also, another point is that there is no IDE that will understand this (at least not in the ones I know) and they will show you an error when using `v3` because it can't find any suitable definition.

Comment: @Xiidref I got it now ! Many thanks for your help and understanding

Answer (score 0):

Don't. Your code should not rely on dynamically creating variables. Use a container, such as a list.

E.g. `vs = [float(line) for line in s]`. Now "`v1`" is at `vs[0]`, "`v2`" is at `vs[1]`, and so on.

Comment: but this will convert the data into a list and that isn't what I want! I want to store the data into independant variables

Comment: @youssef you should not want that. It's bad coding style.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what lists and arrays are intended for. You can store your data in a list that you can later index at each position, as such:

```
s = open("Lines_only.txt", "r")
# Initialize a list
data = []
# Populate list
for line in s:
  data.append(line)
# Now you can index into the list to get your data:
print(data[0])
print(data[3])
```

```
OUTPUT: 
0.9
-0.43
```

Answer (score -1):

The other answers are correct to guide you toward collections. But in those rare cases where you need to create variable names on the fly, you can use `attr()` for object attributes, and either `locals()` or `globals()` for accessing variables through a dictionary interface. Thus:

```py
with open("Lines_only.txt", "r") as s:
    j = 1
    for i in s:
        line = i.strip()
        locals()[f'v{j}'] = float(line)
        j += 1
```